# Linux : power fault input?

Tags: linux, interface, embedded-linux

We are developing a new embedded Linux board.  One feature I would like is the ability to be notified when the power is lost and do a safe shutdown.  Is there any standard mechanism in Linux to indicate a power fail event?  Would prefer not to tie up a full serial line to handle this.

We are developing a custom power supply board so do have the option of building in a small UPS like circuit.  The question is how would that circuit tell Linux that the power has failed?

Comment: not really possible, unless you've got a UPS or other similar external storage system. by definition, if the power's gone out, you can't respond to it, because the board's already dead. so you need something external to supply power for a short interval, plus the notification signal.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: The "safe shutdown" is a simple "/bin/init 0" command in many cases, or the upstart or systemd equivalent.  That's going to be specific to your distro and relatively easy to accomplish.  But wiring that to your power failure signal is a **hardware** question, and nothing in "Linux" is going to help you.  What kind of power management does your board provide?

Comment: I assume you've already checked that you have some kind of hardware support for power-fail detection and you've implemented backup power of some sort. (Linux is neat but it can't magically give your CPU more electrons.) Details on the hardware you want to interact with would help.

Comment: The vast majority of embedded Linux system are probably too cost sensitive to incorporate  any sophisticated power-fail circuitry.  
The typically issue with a dirty shutdown is filesystem integrity.  Typically embedded systems have minimal nonvolatile storage capacity, often using flash memory.  A **journaled filesystem** designed for flash memory, e.g. *JFFS2*, can maintain data integrity in most cases of unexpected shutdowns.  For such systems, no power-fail-detection is needed.

Comment: @sawdust, doesn't Linux do a lot of buffering in RAM so you would lose that if power is suddenly cut?  Also with JFFS2 what happens if the journal write doesn't complete?  I've used JFFS2 before and we've had problems before where an fsck after powering up from a power loss has crashed the kernel due to bugs in filesystem implementation.

Comment: I typically use NOR flash, and JFFS2 supposedly performs minimal buffering.  But NOR ECC and NAND flash will be buffered to coalesce writes. There is a configurable flush timer, which defaults to something like 5 seconds.  Of course you can always force buffers to be flushed with *sync()*.  If a lot of data is being written, then a network connection should be considered.  If loss of data is a real concern, then a backup battery or UPS should be considered.  There is no *fsck* for JFFS2. A journaled FS is not bullet-proof, but it's a simple & low cost solution for many systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [NUT](http://www.networkupstools.org/), the Network UPS Tools. It's probably already packaged for the Linux distro you're using as a base OS.

You might be able to use NUT as-is, out of the box, if your external board can talk to the existing [contact closure driver](http://www.networkupstools.org/docs/developer-guide.chunked/ar01s04.html#contact-closure).

The contact closure interface is only good for a small number of bits of information; flags, if you will. "Power lost", "battery charge failure", and so on. If you need more information back from the power board than that, you could [clone](http://www.networkupstools.org/ups-protocols.html) an existing smart UPS protocol. If for some reason you just had to reinvent the wheel, you can [write a NUT driver](http://www.networkupstools.org/docs/developer-guide.chunked/ar01s04.html) for your custom protocol.

You'll find that most smart UPS protocols use RS-232 serial or USB, but I'm getting a custom embedded Linux vibe from your question. You may want to use I²C or SPI instead, since your microcontroller probably has the I/O pins for it already.

I expect it's clear to you why this is a good idea, since you're already building on top of Linux: NUT is good, stable, available, free infrastructure, just like Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I made something similar for a Linux machine running off of a battery once:

Simply put: Two digital ammeters, one between the battery and the Linux box, and one between the battery and the external power source. These were again connected to the machine via two serial ports. When the external ammeter had a much lower readout than the internal one (more than what could be the result of a fully charged battery), a cron job on the machine would execute a shutdown. And yes, this could probably have been done in a much easier way, if it had been based around an old laptop or something with a battery included, but this was way discarded laptops were easily available :)

In my current job we have Linux systems running in an environment where power failures are to be expected somewhat frequently. A safe shutdown isn't really needed, as a CF card contains the filesystem, which is then booted from in read only mode. Then all of the stuff is read into a RAM disk, so no writes ever happen to the CF card. However, this way you obviously lose the ability to have persistent storage between boots.